# API de notificação não retorna dados

Tags: php, api

Estou tendo um problema com o API de notificação do pagseguro, ele não está retornando o *XML* de maneira alguma, estou testando em *HTTP*, pois em *HTTPS* também não deu certo.

Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Código:

```
<?php
require("includes/connection.php"); //meu banco de dados
require("includes/pagSeguro.php");

header("access-control-allow-origin: https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br");
$email     = 'meugmail@gmail.com';
$token     = 'token';
$pagamento = $_GET['transaction_id'];

$url = 'https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v3/transactions/notifications/' . $pagamento . '?email=' . $email . '&token=' . $token;



$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$transaction = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$dominio = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

if ($transaction == 'Unauthorized') {
    $name = 'unauthorizeds.txt';
    $text = " A transação não foi validada!" . "\r\n";
    $file = fopen($name, 'a+');
    fwrite($file, $text);
    fclose($file);
    exit;
}
$transaction = simplexml_load_string($transaction);
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$date = date('d-m-Y H:i');
$name = 'transaction.txt';
$text = $url = $date . " " . $transaction . "\r\n";
$file = fopen($name, 'a+');
fwrite($file, $text);
fclose($file);

if ($transaction->status >= 1) {
    $transaction_id = $transaction->code;
    $client_id      = $transaction->reference;
    $payment_type   = $transaction->paymentMethod->type;
    if ($payment_type == 1) {
        $payment_method = "Cartão de crédito";
    } elseif ($payment_type == 2) {
        $payment_method = "Boleto";
    } elseif ($payment_type == 3) {
        $payment_method = "Débito online (TEF)";
    } else {
        $payment_method = "Outro";
    }
    $payment_type_method = $transaction->type;
    if ($payment_type_method == 1) {
        $payment_method_transaction = "Pagamento";
    } elseif ($payment_type_method == 11) {
        $payment_method_transaction = "Assinatura";
    } else {
        $payment_method_transaction = "Outro";
    }
    $client_email     = $transaction->sender->email;
    $parceled         = $transaction->installmentCount;
    $parceled_value   = $transaction->installmentFeeAmount;
    $product          = $transaction->items->item->id;
    $product_value    = $transaction->items->item->amount;
    $transaction_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($transaction->date));
    
    $transaction_date_last = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($transaction->lastEventDate));
    if ($transaction->status == 1) {
        $transaction_status = 'Aguardando pagamento';
    } elseif ($transaction->status == 2) {
        $transaction_status = 'Em análise';
    } elseif ($transaction->status == 3) {
        $transaction_status = 'Paga';
    } elseif ($transaction->status == 4) {
        $transaction_status = 'Disponível';
    } elseif ($transaction->status == 5) {
        $transaction_status = 'Em disputa';
    } elseif ($transaction->status == 6) {
        $transaction_status = 'Devolvida';
    } elseif ($transaction->status == 7) {
        $transaction_status = 'Cancelada';
    }
    $client_name = $transaction->sender->name;
    $select      = $mysqli->query("select * from payments where transaction_id = '$transaction->code' ");
    $row         = $select->num_rows;
    $get         = $select->fetch_array();
    if ($row >= 1) {
        $update = $mysqli->query("UPDATE payments SET transaction_id = '$transaction_id', client_email = '$client_email', payment_method = '$payment_method', payment_method_transaction = '$payment_method_transaction', transaction_status = '$transaction_status', transaction_date_last = '$transaction_date_last', product = '$product', product_value = '$product_value', client_name = '$client_name' WHERE transaction_id = '$transaction->code'");
        if ($update) {
            $select       = $mysqli->query("select * from payments where transaction_id = '$transaction->code' ");
            $row          = $select->num_rows;
            $get          = $select->fetch_array();
            $foiPago      = $get['transaction_status'];
            $status       = $get['status'];
            $product_cash = $get['product'];
            if ($foiPago == 'Paga' or $foiPago == 'Disponivel' and $status == '0') {
                $select = $mysqli->query("select * from data where email = '$client_email' ");
                $row    = $select->num_rows;
                $get    = $select->fetch_array();
                $cash   = $get['cash'];
                if ($product_cash == '50KP') {
                    $cash_update = $cash + 50;
                    $update      = $mysqli->query("UPDATE data SET cash = '$cash_update' WHERE email = '$client_email'");
                    $update      = $mysqli->query("UPDATE payments SET status = '1' WHERE transaction_id = '$transaction->code'");
                }
                if ($product_cash == '200KP') {
                    $cash_update = $cash + 200;
                    $update      = $mysqli->query("UPDATE data SET cash = '$cash_update' WHERE email = '$client_email'");
                    $update      = $mysqli->query("UPDATE payments SET status = '1' WHERE transaction_id = '$transaction->code'");
                }
                if ($product_cash == '1000KP') {
                    $cash_update = $cash + 1000;
                    $update      = $mysqli->query("UPDATE data SET cash = '$cash_update' WHERE email = '$client_email'");
                    $update      = $mysqli->query("UPDATE payments SET status = '1' WHERE transaction_id = '$transaction->code'");
                }
                if ($product_cash == '2000KP') {
                    $cash_update = $cash + 2000;
                    $update      = $mysqli->query("UPDATE data SET cash = '$cash_update' WHERE email = '$client_email'");
                    $update      = $mysqli->query("UPDATE payments SET status = '1' WHERE transaction_id = '$transaction->code'");
                }
                
            }
        } else {
            printf("Erro do BD de atualização : %s\n", $mysqli->error);
        }
    } else {
        
        $insert = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `payments`(`transaction_id`, `client_email`, `payment_method`, `payment_method_transaction`, `transaction_status`, `transaction_date`, `transaction_date_last`, `product`, `product_value`, `client_name`) VALUES ('$transaction_id', '$client_email', '$payment_method', '$payment_method_transaction', '$transaction_status', '$transaction_date', '$transaction_date_last', '$product', '$product_value', '$client_name')");
        if ($insert) {
            $select       = $mysqli->query("select * from payments where transaction_id = '$transaction->code' ");
            $row          = $select->num_rows;
            $get          = $select->fetch_array();
            $foiPago      = $get['transaction_status'];
            $status       = $get['status'];
            $product_cash = $get['product'];
            if ($foiPago == 'Paga' or $foiPago == 'Disponivel' and $status == '0') {
                $select = $mysqli->query("select * from data where email = '$client_email' ");
                $row    = $select->num_rows;
                $get    = $select->fetch_array();
                $cash   = $get['cash'];
                if ($product_cash == '50KP') {
                    $cash_update = $cash + 50;
                    $update      = $mysqli->query("UPDATE data SET cash = '$cash_update' WHERE email = '$client_email'");
                    $update      = $mysqli->query("UPDATE payments SET status = '1' WHERE transaction_id = '$transaction->code'");
                }
                if ($product_cash == '200KP') {
                    $cash_update = $cash + 200;
                    $update      = $mysqli->query("UPDATE data SET cash = '$cash_update' WHERE email = '$client_email'");
                    $update      = $mysqli->query("UPDATE payments SET status = '1' WHERE transaction_id = '$transaction->code'");
                }
                if ($product_cash == '1000KP') {
                    $cash_update = $cash + 1000;
                    $update      = $mysqli->query("UPDATE data SET cash = '$cash_update' WHERE email = '$client_email'");
                    $update      = $mysqli->query("UPDATE payments SET status = '1' WHERE transaction_id = '$transaction->code'");
                }
                if ($product_cash == '2000KP') {
                    $cash_update = $cash + 2000;
                    $update      = $mysqli->query("UPDATE data SET cash = '$cash_update' WHERE email = '$client_email'");
                    $update      = $mysqli->query("UPDATE payments SET status = '1' WHERE transaction_id = '$transaction->code'");
                }
                
            }
        } else {
            printf("Erro do BD : %s\n", $mysqli->error);
        }
    }
} else {
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
    $date = date('d-m-Y H:i');
    $name = 'invalids.txt';
    $text = $url = $date . " https://" . $dominio . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "\r\n";
    $file = fopen($name, 'a+');
    fwrite($file, $text);
    fclose($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Já tentei contato com o suporte deles mas tive uma péssima experiência, ai gostaria de ver com vocês, meu código está errado ou seria um problema com a plataforma do pagseguro? Percebi que não estou recebendo o *XML*, no site do pagseguro eles enviam a notificação com status 200, e a comunicação com minha página existe porém é como se não enviassem nada, apenas acessassem ela, pois não vem o código de transição nos logs... quando eu pego o código de notificação no pagseguro e insiro na url manualmente, tudo funciona perfeitamente... então estou achando que eles não estão enviando o código, só não sei de quem é o erro.

Comment: Insere um `var_dump($transaction);exit(2);` após `$transaction= curl_exec($curl);` e posta aí o que ele retorna.

Comment: @JacksonAntunes para salvar um log "customizado" pode fazer assim: `error_log(var_dump($transaction,true))`. A função [error_log()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.error-log.php) vai salvar o conteudo do `var_dump()`, pode ser print_r, string ou qualquer outra coisa, no mesmo arquivo de log do php, ai facilita nao ter que fazer `file_put_contents()` e similares

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro estava na forma que eu tentava obter os dados, pois não tinha entendido bem como funcionava o api de notificação. Ao invés da variável ser `$pagamento = $_GET['transaction_id'];` era  `$pagamento = $_POST['notificationCode'];`.

No caso do transaction_id é para quando o PagSeguro redireciona o cliente para uma página prédefinida pelo usuário, então a informação seria pega dessa forma

```
$pagamento = $_GET['transaction_id'];
```

No caso do api de notificação eu quero o código da notificação, e não o da transação... para isso eu pego ele usando o parâmetro `notificationCode`.